# How to evaluate all derivatives of a polynomial at a point with FFT?

Tags: fourier-transform

I found [this problem](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap32.htm):

> Evaluating all derivatives of a polynomial at a point
>
> Given a polynomial A(x) of degree-bound n, its tth derivative is
>   defined by
>
> [image: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/798_a.gif]
>
> From the coefficient representation $(a_0, a_1, . . . , a_{n-1})$ of A(x) and
>   a given point $x_0$, we wish to determine A(t) ($x_0$) for t = 0, 1, . . . ,
>   n - 1.

I know the vector of the coefficients has to be used and I also know that the derivative of a term $ax^n$ is $a*n*x^{n-1}$, but where do I go from there?

I can only think of the naïve scheme to evaluate this: Find the first derivative ($O(n)$), evaluate it using Horner's method ($O(n)$). Repeat this for all deterivaties, giving $(O(n^2)$).

Comment: The link you provide has guidance toward solving your exercise, which is exercise 32-3. Have you tried following the detailed steps stated there? If not, I suggest you start with that, and if you get stuck you can ask a more specific question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Taking the derivative has a certain, simple diagonal effect on the Fourier transform, that hopefully was covered in class. Hence if you compute the Fourier transform of the original function, you "know" the Fourier transform of all its derivatives as well. Given the Fourier transform, there is a formula for the value of the actual function. In your case, in order to compute the value of all derivatives of the function at a point, you multiply some matrix by the vector of Fourier coefficients. This matrix looks suspiciously similar to the DFT matrix, so hopefully you can compute the matrix-vector product in time $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the coverage was very cursory/high-level (evaluate->pairwise product->interpolate with the first and last step calling the divide-and-conquer FFT algorithm). Could you explain what you mean by Fourier transform? Is this the Vandermonde matrix consisting of roots of unity?

Comment: "compute the Fourier transform of the original function" I only saw Fourier transform in the context of multiplying two polynomials of one variable. Here there is only one value.

Comment: @cs-newbie The Fourier transform is what the FFT algorithm is computing.